# Hibernate Bitwise operation function not getting registered

Tags: mysql, hibernate, function, bit-manipulation

I am trying to register a function in hibernate to do bitwise AND (&) and bitwise OR (|) in mysql 5.

So far I have a custom mysql dialect:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.***.hibernate.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">...</property>
</bean>
```

Here is my custom dialect code:

```
public class MySQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect {
    public MySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("bitwise_and", new BitwiseAndFunction("bitwise_and"));
    }
}
```

and here is my custom function:

```
public class BitwiseAndFunction extends StandardSQLFunction implements SQLFunction {

public BitwiseAndFunction(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public BitwiseAndFunction(String name, Type type) {
    super(name, type);
}

public String render(List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory)
        throws QueryException {
    if (args.size() != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "the function must be passed 2 arguments");
    }
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(args.get(0).toString());
    buffer.append(" & ").append(args.get(1));
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

}

The problem is whenever I use bitwise_and in an HQL query, it gives me a long stack trace beginning with:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: bitwise_and near line 1, column 354 [select sqrt(pow(rideRequest.startLatitude - p.latitude, 2) + pow(rideRequest.startLongitude - p.longitude, 2)) as distance, p.polyLine.rideOffer as rideOffer, p.polyLine.rideOffer.user, p.polyLine.rideOffer.user.role from com.freeride.lib.domain.Point p, com.freeride.lib.domain.RideRequest rideRequest where rideRequest.id=? and (rideOffer.permissions bitwise_and rideRequest.permissions) = rideRequest.permissions group by p.polyLine.rideOffer order by distance asc]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found my own solution. The old way of doing custom hql functions was deprecated in Hibernate 3.6.0, so in my more current version (4.2.5) I had to use:

```
import java.lang.Integer;
public class MyDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect {
    public MyDialect() {
        super();
        //THIS DOES NOT WORK!
        registerFunction("bitwise_andOne", new BitwiseAndFunction("poop"));
        //THIS WORKS!
        registerFunction("bitwise_andTwo", new SQLFunctionTemplate(IntegerType.INSTANCE, "(?1 & ?2)"));
    }
}
```

Basicly, the second method works and the previous one does not. I don't know why.

You can call bitwise_and2 in any hql query programmatically. For example:

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.createQuery("select * from people person where bitwise_andTwo(person.permissions, 7)

the resulting sql will be something like

select * from people where people.permissions & 7 = permissions

This fixed my problem.